# Modifying a substring of an attribute in a node and all children

Tags: xml, xslt

I've done quite a bit of searching and haven't quite been able to come up with anything yet using XSLT.  I'm trying to take an XML template (for McPAT, partially shown below) dictating system specs and duplicate the `component id="system.core0" name="core0"` node so I can have N core nodes.  Each one will have to have "system.core#" as the id and "core#" as the name with # being the core number, 0-n.

I also have to duplicate this in any descendant nodes such as the system.core0.itlb node below.

Even further, in any of the descendant nodes with a value such as "config.system.cpu.clock", I have to append the node number to "cpu."

Finally, I have to overwrite 
    `param name="number_of_cores" value="1"`
under system with 
    `param name="number_of_cores" value="n"`
and change 
    `param name="homogenous_cores" value="1"`
to 
    `param name="homogenous_cores" value="0"`

The XML currently looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<component id="root" name="root">
    <component id="system" name="system">
         <param name="number_of_cores" value="1"/>
         <param name="homogeneous_cores" value="1"/>
         <param name="number_of_L1Directories" value="0"/>
         <param name="number_of_L2Directories" value="0"/>
         <param name="number_of_L2s" value="1"/> 
         <param name="Private_L2" value="0"/>
         <param name="number_of_L3s" value="0"/> 
         <param name="number_of_NoCs" value="1"/>
         ...
         <component id="system.core0" name="core0">
             <!-- Core property -->
             <param name="clock_rate" value="{1e-6/config.system.cpu.clock*1e12}"/>
             <param name="opt_local" value="1"/>      
             <stat name="total_instructions" value="{stats.system.cpu.iq.iqInstsIssued}"/>

             ...
             <component id="system.core0.itlb" name="itlb">
                 <param name="number_entries" value="{config.system.cpu.itb.size}"/>
                 <stat name="total_accesses" value="{stats.system.cpu.itb.fetch_accesses}"/>
                 ...
             </component>
         </component>
     </component>
 </component>
```

There are quite a few lines here.  I've already gone and copied the system.core0 node N times, thanks to SO.  I would post the link but I can't find the page.  I do know that Dimitre Novatchev put the answer that I followed though and I'd like to give him credit for his help with that.  So far, the XSLT stylesheet looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="n" select="5"/>

    <!--Identity template-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="component[@id='system']/component[@name='core0']">
        <xsl:call-template name="copyNtimes">
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="core_num" select="1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="copyNtimes">
        <xsl:param name="n" select="0"/>
        <xsl:param name="core_num" select="1"/>

        <xsl:if test="$n > 0">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
            <xsl:text>
            </xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="copyNtimes">
                <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n -1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="core_num" select="$core_num+1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So at the end of running this through xsltproc, I have the original with system.core0 duplicated N times.  What's left has been driving me crazy for days.  How do I go about changing the core numbers for each new node I create, reflecting that in all child nodes as well?  Any help at all would help, even if it's not code.  I've played around with making new templates and using copy-of but nothing seems to be getting me closer.

I could also bring this all into another language such as Perl where I can run the XSLT stylesheet to duplicate change and manually modify the attribute strings if that'd be easier.  I know Perl has some pretty good modules for both XML and XSLT.  I feel that XSLT should be able to do this,though, and since I'm new to it, the format is throwing me off.

**Edit**:
An example output of what I need is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <component id="root" name="root">
        <component id="system" name="system">
             <param name="number_of_cores" value="3"/>
             <param name="homogeneous_cores" value="0"/>
             <param name="number_of_L1Directories" value="0"/>
             <param name="number_of_L2Directories" value="0"/>
             <param name="number_of_L2s" value="1"/> 
             <param name="Private_L2" value="0"/>
             <param name="number_of_L3s" value="0"/> 
             <param name="number_of_NoCs" value="1"/>
             <!--...-->
             <component id="system.core0" name="core0">
                 <!-- Core property -->
                 <param name="clock_rate" value="{1e-6/config.system.cpu0.clock*1e12}"/>
                 <param name="opt_local" value="1"/>      
                 <stat name="total_instructions" value="{stats.system.cpu0.iq.iqInstsIssued}"/>
                 <!--...-->
                 <component id="system.core0.itlb" name="itlb">
                     <param name="number_entries" value="{config.system.cpu0.itb.size}"/>
                     <stat name="total_accesses" value="{stats.system.cpu0.itb.fetch_accesses}"/>
                     ...
                 </component>
             </component>
             <component id="system.core1" name="core1">
                 <!-- Core property -->
                 <param name="clock_rate" value="{1e-6/config.system.cpu1.clock*1e12}"/>
                 <param name="opt_local" value="1"/>      
                 <stat name="total_instructions" value="{stats.system.cpu1.iq.iqInstsIssued}"/>
                 <!--...-->
                 <component id="system.core1.itlb" name="itlb">
                     <param name="number_entries" value="{config.system.cpu1.itb.size}"/>
                     <stat name="total_accesses" value="{stats.system.cpu1.itb.fetch_accesses}"/>
                     ...
                 </component>
             </component><component id="system.core2" name="core2">
                 <!-- Core property -->
                 <param name="clock_rate" value="{1e-6/config.system.cpu2.clock*1e12}"/>
                 <param name="opt_local" value="1"/>      
                 <stat name="total_instructions" value="{stats.system.cpu2.iq.iqInstsIssued}"/>
                 <!--...-->
                 <component id="system.core2.itlb" name="itlb">
                     <param name="number_entries" value="{config.system.cpu2.itb.size}"/>
                     <stat name="total_accesses" value="{stats.system.cpu2.itb.fetch_accesses}"/>
                     ...
                 </component>
             </component>
         </component>
     </component>
```

Comment: From where should the value `n` come in the new `param name="number_of_cores" value="n"`?  Always from the global param named `n` in the XSLT?

Comment: In the XSLT stylesheet, I have it passes as a param, set at the top of the file.  I'd assume I can just use it there but in case that's impossible, I'm sure I can just make a comment at the top that it will have to be modified in different places for changes in n.

Comment: This seems to be a legit question, but it is hard to understand the prose. Please show an actual XML output and explain how it differs from what you need.

Comment: @kjhughes actually just posted an answer that fixes one of the problems I was having and included its output.  Beyond that, however, you'll see that core0 is duplicated multiple times.  For each subsequent code0 node, I want to change it to core1, core2, etc.  I also need that to be reflected in all its descendants, as their id's will be system.core0.* as well.

Comment: I just updated with an example output of what I'm trying to achieve as well

Comment: Thanks - Now your question is worth an upvote!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(1)** If you add the following two templates to your XSLT,

```
  <xsl:template match="param[@name='number_of_cores' and @value='1']">
    <param name="number_of_cores" value="{$n}"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="param[@name='homogeneous_cores' and @value='1']">
    <param name="homogenous_cores" value="0"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

you will override the identity transformation and be able to output different `param` elements as illustrated above.

**(2)** If you adjust the copying within `copyNtimes` as follows,

```
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="id" select="concat('system.core', $n)"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="name" select="concat('core', $n)"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
```

you will generate not carbon copies but copies where `@id` and `@name` reflect the copy number passed to `copyNtimes`.

**(3)** If you further adjust the `xsl:apply-template` in `copyNtimes` to tunnel `n` (XSLT 2.0 required),

```
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
    <xsl:with-param name="compNum" tunnel="yes" select="$n"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
```

and also add a template to handle `itlb` `components` on the other side of the tunnel,

```
  <xsl:template match="component[@name='itlb']">
    <xsl:param name="compNum" tunnel="yes"/>
    <component name="itlb" value="{concat('system.core',$compNum,'.itlb')}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </component>
  </xsl:template>
```

you can work the component number into the descendent `itlb` `components`.

Updated (for a third time) complete code and sample input/output XML documents follow...

**This input XML document:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<component id="root" name="root">
  <component id="system" name="system">
    <param name="number_of_cores" value="1"/>
    <param name="homogeneous_cores" value="1"/>
    <param name="number_of_L1Directories" value="0"/>
    <param name="number_of_L2Directories" value="0"/>
    <param name="number_of_L2s" value="1"/> 
    <param name="Private_L2" value="0"/>
    <param name="number_of_L3s" value="0"/> 
    <param name="number_of_NoCs" value="1"/>
    <!-- ... -->
    <component id="system.core0" name="core0">
      <!-- Core property -->
      <param name="clock_rate" value="{1e-6/config.system.cpu.clock*1e12}"/>
      <param name="opt_local" value="1"/>      
      <stat name="total_instructions" value="{stats.system.cpu.iq.iqInstsIssued}"/>

      <!-- ... -->
      <component id="system.core0.itlb" name="itlb">
        <param name="number_entries" value="{config.system.cpu.itb.size}"/>
        <stat name="total_accesses" value="{stats.system.cpu.itb.fetch_accesses}"/>
        <!-- ... -->
      </component>
    </component>
  </component>
</component>
```

**Given to this XSLT transformation:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="n" select="5"/>

  <!--Identity template-->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="param[@name='number_of_cores' and @value='1']">
    <param name="number_of_cores" value="{$n}"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="param[@name='homogeneous_cores' and @value='1']">
    <param name="homogenous_cores" value="0"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="component[@name='itlb']">
    <xsl:param name="compNum" tunnel="yes"/>
    <component name="itlb" value="{concat('system.core',$compNum,'.itlb')}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </component>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="component[@id='system']/component[@name='core0']">
    <xsl:call-template name="copyNtimes">
      <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="core_num" select="1"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="copyNtimes">
    <xsl:param name="n" select="0"/>
    <xsl:param name="core_num" select="1"/>

    <xsl:if test="$n > 0">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="id" select="concat('system.core', $n)"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="name" select="concat('core', $n)"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
          <xsl:with-param name="compNum" tunnel="yes" select="$n"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
      <xsl:text>
      </xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="copyNtimes">
        <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n -1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="core_num" select="$core_num+1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Will yield this output XML document:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<component id="root" name="root">
  <component id="system" name="system">
      <param name="number_of_cores" value="5"/>
      <param name="homogenous_cores" value="0"/>
      <param name="number_of_L1Directories" value="0"/>
      <param name="number_of_L2Directories" value="0"/>
      <param name="number_of_L2s" value="1"/> 
      <param name="Private_L2" value="0"/>
      <param name="number_of_L3s" value="0"/> 
      <param name="number_of_NoCs" value="1"/>
      <!-- ... -->
      <component id="system.core5" name="core5">
      <!-- Core property -->
         <param name="clock_rate" value="{1e-6/config.system.cpu.clock*1e12}"/>
         <param name="opt_local" value="1"/>      
         <stat name="total_instructions" value="{stats.system.cpu.iq.iqInstsIssued}"/>

         <!-- ... -->
         <component name="itlb" value="system.core5.itlb">
            <param name="number_entries" value="{config.system.cpu.itb.size}"/>
            <stat name="total_accesses" value="{stats.system.cpu.itb.fetch_accesses}"/>
            <!-- ... -->
         </component>
      </component>
      <component id="system.core4" name="core4">
      <!-- Core property -->
         <param name="clock_rate" value="{1e-6/config.system.cpu.clock*1e12}"/>
         <param name="opt_local" value="1"/>      
         <stat name="total_instructions" value="{stats.system.cpu.iq.iqInstsIssued}"/>

         <!-- ... -->
         <component name="itlb" value="system.core4.itlb">
            <param name="number_entries" value="{config.system.cpu.itb.size}"/>
            <stat name="total_accesses" value="{stats.system.cpu.itb.fetch_accesses}"/>
            <!-- ... -->
         </component>
      </component>
      <component id="system.core3" name="core3">
      <!-- Core property -->
         <param name="clock_rate" value="{1e-6/config.system.cpu.clock*1e12}"/>
         <param name="opt_local" value="1"/>      
         <stat name="total_instructions" value="{stats.system.cpu.iq.iqInstsIssued}"/>

         <!-- ... -->
         <component name="itlb" value="system.core3.itlb">
            <param name="number_entries" value="{config.system.cpu.itb.size}"/>
            <stat name="total_accesses" value="{stats.system.cpu.itb.fetch_accesses}"/>
            <!-- ... -->
         </component>
      </component>
      <component id="system.core2" name="core2">
      <!-- Core property -->
         <param name="clock_rate" value="{1e-6/config.system.cpu.clock*1e12}"/>
         <param name="opt_local" value="1"/>      
         <stat name="total_instructions" value="{stats.system.cpu.iq.iqInstsIssued}"/>

         <!-- ... -->
         <component name="itlb" value="system.core2.itlb">
            <param name="number_entries" value="{config.system.cpu.itb.size}"/>
            <stat name="total_accesses" value="{stats.system.cpu.itb.fetch_accesses}"/>
            <!-- ... -->
         </component>
      </component>
      <component id="system.core1" name="core1">
      <!-- Core property -->
         <param name="clock_rate" value="{1e-6/config.system.cpu.clock*1e12}"/>
         <param name="opt_local" value="1"/>      
         <stat name="total_instructions" value="{stats.system.cpu.iq.iqInstsIssued}"/>

         <!-- ... -->
         <component name="itlb" value="system.core1.itlb">
            <param name="number_entries" value="{config.system.cpu.itb.size}"/>
            <stat name="total_accesses" value="{stats.system.cpu.itb.fetch_accesses}"/>
            <!-- ... -->
         </component>
      </component>

  </component>
</component>
```

Comment: That is actually exactly what I needed for that problem!  I also need to change core0 to core0, core1, core2,...,core(n-1) for each separate instance of the core.

Comment: Answer updated.  You're getting two answers for the price of one here.  ;-)

Comment: Thanks!  That's definitely very helpful!  Is there a way, along the same lines, to apply that same logic to the descendant nodes so that, for instance, under "system.core4", there would be a component "system.core4.itlb" instead of "system.core0.itlb"

Comment: Answer updated again.  As this has drifted well past a single SO question, this'll be my last update.  I hope I've shown you enough that you can take over from here.

Comment: Yes, this is most definitely what I needed.  You've helped so much!  Thanks!

Comment: I'd actually like to thank you again, now a day later.  I took what you used, modified it a bit to be able to use xslt1.0, and was able to figure out the rest of the problem as well. This was a HUGE help.